# How do I reset a matrix uniform for a WebGL program?

Tags: webgl

I am trying to reset a 2vfloat matrix uniform of a WebGL program like this.

```
var uniformInformation = myContext.getActiveUniform(myProgram, 8);
var uniformLocation = myContext.getUniformLocation(myProgram, uniformInformation.name);
myContext.uniformMatrix2fv(uniformLocation, false, new Float32Array(uniformInformation.size / 4));
```

However, I get the following error when I do this:

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: uniformMatrix2fv: invalid size
```

Does the size property of `uniformInformation` mean something other than the size in bytes? I have also tried taking out the `/ 4` with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know a name and type of your uniform variable, why are you making it so hard when you can just do this:

```
var mat2d = new Float32Array(4); // or identity matrix - new Float32Array([1,0,0,1]); 
myContext.uniformMatrix2fv(uniformLocation, false, mat2d);
```